# Why does React's onContextMenu work in Chrome on disabled elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, dom-events, contextmenu

I found something very strange. In all major browsers, context menu event doesn't work on disabled elements, so this wouldn't print to console:

```html
<button
    type="button"
    onContextMenu="console.log(123)"
    disabled
>
    Click me
</button>
```

But it's a little different with React. I tried to do the same thing through React component:

```
const MyComponent = () => (
    <button
        type="button"
        onContextMenu={() => console.log(123)}
        disabled
    >
        Click me
    </button>
);
```

This time, in Chrome it prints to the console, but in other browsers it does not. For educational purpose, I'm trying to understand what is the difference between HTML's `onContextMenu` and React's `onContextMenu` plus why only Chrome handles it differently. Super weird.

Reproduced in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-rain-tggl7p)

Answer (score 1):

I spent a while digging into this. It seems like a bug in Chrome where `contextmenu`, despite being a type of `PointerEvent`, fires on disabled elements *but only* **when bubbling**.

Here's a JSFiddle without React: https://jsfiddle.net/bpe0yoc6/4/

```js
// Only in chrome does this fire
document.querySelector("#root").addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => { console.log("contextmenu fired", e.target.tagName) })

document.querySelector("#root").addEventListener("click", (e) => { console.log("click fired", e.target.tagName) })
```

```css
#root {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <button
      type="button"
      disabled
  >
      Click me
  </button>
</div>
```

React registers event handles at the root of the DOM tree, which is why doing this:

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => { ... })
```

will not fire on the disabled button, and neither will `oncontextmenu`.

I opened an issue on the Chromium issue tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1421370

Comment: I can create an issue to fix this up in ReactJS.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I'd create an issue in Chrome, why would React patch this?

Comment: Slava, awesome investigation! I'll have a deeper look later and accept your answer if I'm able to reproduce the idea.

Comment: @RoboRobok React does [handles this behavior](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/1f1f8eb559d064c5b1954e5dde7517d87d594e7a/packages/react-dom-bindings/src/events/getListener.js#L23) for other mouse events. I created this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/26298)

Comment: @OluwafemiSule React doesn't do anything. It's the browsers that ignore mouse events on disabled elements. And in case of `onContextMenu`, Chrome forgets to do that for bubbled event, assuming that Slava's colclusions are correct.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like it does indeed ignore them explicitly. I wonder why.

Comment: Maybe preempting event bubbling in the dom.

Answer (score 1):

According to Chromium, this is intentional. See the [issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1421369#c6).

> This is an intentional change and matches what firefox nightly, who also implemented the new behavior, is doing.
> I have temporarily disabled the new behavior due to other issues, but I will re-enable it soon.
> The disabled attribute is only supposed to block click events, not contextmenu events. Can you just call preventDefault() on the contextmenu event?

Sounds like an explicit check is now required.